# Ruby thinks element of hash is Integer

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a function in Ruby:

```
def find_item(keyword)
    potential = []
    $items.each do |item|
        puts item                                 # <-- for debugging purposes
        if item["name"].downcase== keyword
            potential << item["name"].downcase
        elsif item["keywords"].index(keyword) != nil
            potential << item["name"].downcase
        end
    end
    return potential
end
```

(The global variable `$items` is a Hash object that maps a few strings to some values that determine the properties of the `item`.)

When I `puts` the current item it is iterating over (the line with the comment does just that), it gives me:

`{"name"=>"Thing1", "keywords"=>["thing", "green"], ...}`

but when I try `item["name"]` on the next line (which should definitely return `Thing1`), it gives me:

`C:/somepath/someprogram.rb:125:in '[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$items` is a Hash, then `$items.each do |item|` will yield `[key, value]` pairs (Arrays) to the block. If you only want the values, use `each_value`.

Comment: And if you need both key and value, use destructuring bind.

Comment: In case "destructuring bind" is unknown to you (I myself never heard it in the Ruby community), he means doing something like `$items.each do |key, value|`

Comment: Ahh ok that seems to be the problem :) Thanks!